# difference between inner join vs multiple ands

Tags: mysql

I have following 3 SQL tables:

```
    mysql> select * FROM borrower;
+--------+------------+---------+--------------+
| cardno | name       | address | phone        |
+--------+------------+---------+--------------+
|      1 | A          | nj,usa  | 111-222-333 |
|      2 | B          | NY,USA  | 444-555-666 |
|      3 | C          | nj,usa  | 777-888-999 |
+--------+------------+---------+--------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * FROM bookloans;
+--------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
| bookid | branchid | cardno | dateout    | duedate    |
+--------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
|      1 |        1 |      1 | 2014-04-01 | 2014-08-01 |
|      2 |        1 |      1 | 2014-04-02 | 2014-08-02 |
|      3 |        2 |      2 | 2014-04-04 | 2014-07-05 |
+--------+----------+--------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> select * FROM books;
+--------+------------+---------+------
| bookid | title      | publishername | 
+--------+------------+---------+------
|      1 | Atitle     | tmh           |
|      2 | Btitle     | tmh           |
|      3 | Ctitle     | tmh           |
+--------+------------+---------+-----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * FROM librarybranch;
+----------+------------+--------+
| branchid | branchname | address|
+--------+----------+--------+---+
|        1 | abc loc    | nj,usa  |
|        2 | def loc    | NY,USA  |
+----------+------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I want to execute a query that shows book title,borrowersname,borrowers address for
 each book loaned out by "def loc" branch whose duedate is today(2014-07-05). I came up
 with two possible queries:

**1.Query based on joins:**

```
select books.title,borrower.name,librarybranch.branchname from (( bookloans inner join  
borrower on bookloans.cardno = borrower.cardno) inner join books on bookloans.bookid = 
books.bookid inner join librarybranch on bookloans.branchid=librarybranch.branchid) 
where duedate='2014-07-05' and branchname="def loc";
```

**2.Query based on mutiple ands:**

```
select b.title,r.name,r.address from books b,borrower r,bookloans bl,librarybranch lb 
where lb.branchname='def loc' and lb.branchid = bl.branchid and bl.duedate='2014-07-05' 
and bl.cardno=r.cardno and bl.bookid=b.bookid;
```

To me, query based on joins is most intuitive, we are creating a giant table with all the rows from different tables joined together and then querying this giant table based on columns from multiple tables. However I find it surprising that query based on multiple ands gives same result. My question is is option 2 above (one based on multiple ands) exactly equivalent to option 1 (doing inner joins). If not, what's the difference? They seem to give identical results in this case.

Comment: The terms you're seeking are "_implicit_" (comma-separated `FROM` clause` vs "_explicit_" joins.

Comment: [There are a few other questions addressing](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+implicit+vs+explicit+join) this in different ways, besides the main one I linked.